# Node.js session login

Tags: node.js, session, express

Node.js does not seem to be remembering my session.

I am using Express with `cookie-parser` and `express-session` as middleware.

In my application, I use Mongo to keep usernames and passwords.

The following is a MWE:

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser({
    secret: 'derma-aid'
}));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'derma-aid',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {secure: false}
}));

// CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) headers to support Cross-site HTTP requests
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With');
    next();
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res)
{
    console.log('login');
    req.session.user_id = 500;
    res.send('<h1>login</h1>');
});

app.get('/view', function(req, res)
{
    console.log('view id: ' + req.session.user_id);
    res.send('<h1>view: ' + req.session.user_id + '</h1>');
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res)
{
    console.log('logout: ' + req.session.user_id);
    res.send('<h1>logout: ' + req.session.user_id + '</h1>');
    delete req.session.user_id;
});

app.listen(5000);
```

If you go to the browser to `http://localhost:5000/login`, then `req.session.user_id` should be set and displayed correctly on `http://localhost:5000/view`.

But, instead, I am getting undefined messages...

**EDIT:** `cookie: {secure: false}` as suggested by @tiblu. I get this error: `TypeError: Secret string must be provided.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your session middleware setup change from:
`cookie: {secure: true}`
to
`cookie: {secure: false}`

Cookies marked as secure are not sent for NON-HTTPS requests. You are accessing your application over HTTP.

More reading on that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_cookie

Comment: Oh, right. It does complain now about `TypeError: Secret string must be provided.`.

Comment: I managed to fix this error I was getting. It was due to using `cookieParser({secret: 'derma-aid'})`, instead of just `cookieParser('derma-aid')`. I got confused because most express libraries use dictionary for the options.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix the `TypeError: Secret string must be provided.`

```
- app.use(cookieParser({
-     secret: 'derma-aid'
- }));
+ app.use(cookieParser(
+     'derma-aid'
+ ));
```